# Differences between databricks dbx execute and launch command

Tags: databricks, databricks-dbx

I have a project for which I want to be able to run some entry points on databricks. I used dbx for that, having the following `deployment.yaml` file:

```
build:
  python: "poetry"

environments:
  default:
    workflows:
      - name: "test"
        existing_cluster_id: "my-culster-id"
        spark_python_task:
          python_file: "file://tests/test.py"
```

I'm able to run the test script with the `execute` command:

```
poetry run dbx execute --cluster-id=my-culster-id test
```

My problem with this option is that it launches the script interactively and I can't really retrieve the executed code on Databricks, except by looking at the cluster's logs.

So I tried using the `deploy` and `launch` commands, such that a proper job is created and run on Databricks.

```
poetry run dbx deploy test && poetry run dbx launch test
```

However the job run fails with the following error, which I don't understand:

```
Run result unavailable: job failed with error message
Library installation failed for library due to user error. Error messages:
'Manage' permissions are required to modify libraries on a cluster
```

In any case, what do you think is the best way to run a job that can be traced on Databricks from my local machine ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on doc [here](https://dbx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/#whats-the-difference-between-dbx-execute-and-dbx-launch):

> The dbx execute command runs your code on all-purpose cluster. It's
> very handy for interactive development and data exploration.
>
> Don't use dbx execute for production workloads
>
> It's not recommended to use dbx execute for production workloads. Run
> your workflows on the dedicated job clusters instead. Reasoning is
> described in detail in the concepts section.
>
> In contrast to the dbx execute, dbx launch launches your workflow on a
> dedicated job cluster. This is a recommended way for CI pipelines,
> automated launches etc.

Comment: Thanks, yes it's clearer with this doc, in combination with this page: https://dbx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/concepts/cluster_types/#summary